# JSDoc 3 How to Read .c or .h files that have #include? (# is an illegal character)

Tags: javascript, jsdoc, documentation-generation, jsdoc3

I am currently trying to use **JSDoc 3** to generate a documentation guide in HTML. Some of the files I am using to make the guide are **.h** and **.c** files that contain lines of code beginning with **#include** and **#ifndef**.

However, when I run the jsdoc, I get an error from those lines saying that **# is an illegal character**. Is there some sort of plugin I can write to correct this issue? How can I run my project without getting an error for the lines of code beginning with **#**?

Answer (score 2):

JSDoc is for documenting JavaScript code. As per JSDoc contributor:

> JSDoc doesn't really support integrating docs for C++ or other languages.

Pls see more on [JSDoc request for C++ Addons](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/1041). One of the suggestions is to use [documentationjs](https://github.com/documentationjs/documentation) project instead.

Comment: This documentation guide used to be generated using JSDoc2. When JSDoc2 was used I was able to generate the document from a combination of javascript, html templates, .c, and .h files. Now that I need to update the documentation guide to be generated using JSDoc3 I cannot get the process to work. I am sure there is some way to make it work since it was doable on the older, outdated version of JSDoc, but I am not sure how to make it work and am having some difficulty finding relevant material online. Any help towards finding a solution for this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @MatthewCordone probably the good idea would be to talk directly to developers through [github issues feedback](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues). They may response much faster. If you find out some available solution please have a minute and post it back into SO to contribute other ppl looking the same answer.

Comment: I posted an issue to the github page that you mentioned above. There seems to be a bit of a backlog of issues on that page, so hopefully it won't take too long to hear back. I will post here if I actually hear back with a viable solution. In the mean time, if anyone else has any suggestions on how to deal with this problem please post them.